# How to remove/hide the search field using the sDom prop of datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the [jquery-datatables](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) for generating tables.
I was wondering if there is any way i could remove/hide the 'Search' field from above the table. I'm not quite clear on how does the `sDom` property of datatables work, but i tried this:

```
    "sDom": '<"top">tip', //not quite sure how can i remove the search from the table.
```

Any ideas on how the `sDom` work?

Comment: Do you just want to remove the filter, or you *must* use `sDom` ?

Comment: Use `'<"top">tip'` as you are suggestion yourself. It works right away, see example (1.10.x) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9Lfd150e/** whats wrong with that? Basically, the default `sDom` / `dom` is `lfrtip`, so you simply just have to define `sDom` **without** the `f`- parameter.

Comment: regarding "how sDom works" -> **http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sDom**   or **http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom**

Comment: well, the issue is if i use "'<"top">tip'", the search filter is gone along with the info i placed in <div class="top">. i can only see an empty <div> in place. i want the info in "top" intact and only remove the search filter. the "'<"top">tip'" removes everything from the top

Comment: @ TJ: i want to just remove the search filter. whatever is in the <div "top"> i want it intact.

Comment: then use `sDom : '<"top">lrtip'` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/g9dfej2z/** dont know what your "info" is, you did never mentioned that. Or better remove / hide the filter container - `$('.dataTables_filter').remove();` see -> **http://jsfiddle.net/44kjrafk/** in my opinion the recommended way. Removing the filter "dom-style" (the `f`-option) disables the ability to filter in general (you cant even filter by code) so this is defently the way to go for you.

Comment: Thanks @ davidkonrad. the ".remove()" did the job!!